# Python splitting values from urllib in string

Tags: python, url, split, urllib2

I'm trying to get IP location and other stuff from ipinfodb.com, but I'm stuck.

I want to split all of the values into new strings that I can format how I want later. What I wrote so far is:

```
resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=mykey&ip=someip').read()
    out = resp.replace(";", " ")
    print out
```

Before I replaced the string into new one the output was:

```
OK;;someip;somecountry;somecountrycode;somecity;somecity;-;42.1975;23.3342;+05:00
```

So I made it show only

```
OK someip somecountry somecountrycode somecity somecity - 42.1975;23.3342 +05:00
```

But the problem is that this is pretty stupid, because I want to use them not in one string, but in more, because what I do now is `print out` and it outputs this, I want to change it like `print country`, `print city` and it outputs the country,city etc. I tried checking in their site, there's some class for that but it's for different api version so I can't use it (v2, mine is v3). Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

PS. Sorry if the answer is obvious or I'm mistaken, I'm new with Python :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the `resp` text by `;`:

```
out = resp.split(';')
```

Now `out` is a list of values instead, use indexes to access various items:

```
print 'Country: {}'.format(out[3])
```

Alternatively, add `format=json` to your query string and receive a [JSON response](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php) from that API:

```
import json

resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?format=json&key=mykey&ip=someip')
data = json.load(resp)

print data['countryName']
```

Comment: Oh yeah I did resp.split by ;, but never knew I can format them lol. Thanks! Edit: Yes that's the lib I was talking about, it's for api version 2.

Comment: @maikati: ah, removed the library link then. It's really just a thin wrapper in any case.